# Visual Studio 2019 Will Not Publish An App

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio will not publish my app. It is trowing an error

```
Unable to copy file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll"
```

It is trying to copy to the app bin folder:

```
 bin\Debug\app.publish\Application Files\myAp\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll.deploy'.
```

I have tried restarting VS I have deleted the bin folder cleaned the project and re-built but no luck. Has anyone come across this problem.

Comment: Temporarily disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.

Comment: Thanks but I don't have any anti-malware products installed.